# Does pandas filtering support aliases?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a filtering operation in *pandas* :

```
   first_replies_wo_comments = pandas.read_csv(path)

   recent = first_replies_wo_comments[
    (first_replies_wo_comments.POST_CREATED_AT > '2018-02-01') & 
    (first_replies_wo_comments.POST_CREATED_AT < '2018-03-13')
   ]
```

Notice that the name of the dataframe `first_replies_wo_comments` is specified three times. If there were additional filtering conditions it would be even more. Is there any way to *alias* the df - in a manner similar to aliases in `SQL`?

*Update*  I was/am aware of `dataframe.query()`. I am wondering what options exist when using the parenthesized approach (inside `[]`). Thanks!

Comment: `x = first_replies_wo_comments` then just `x.POST_CREATED_AT ...`

Comment: Why not create a variable `date_field = first_replies_wo_comments.POST_CREATED_AT`? Even better, use `pd.Series.between`, i.e. `date_field.between(x, y, inclusive=False)`.

Comment: You can also use `df.query()` which takes a query string which lets you access columns without the data-frame name. That may have (good or bad) performance implications, though. But again, in general, you could just assign to another, shorter name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for this and you can chain each new condition:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'POST_CREATED_AT': pd.date_range('20180128', periods=7)})
print(df)

  POST_CREATED_AT
0      2018-01-28
1      2018-01-29
2      2018-01-30
3      2018-01-31
4      2018-02-01
5      2018-02-02
6      2018-02-03
```

---

```
df_filter = df.query('POST_CREATED_AT > 20180201').query('POST_CREATED_AT < 20180313')
print(df_filter)

  POST_CREATED_AT
5      2018-02-02
6      2018-02-03
```

**Another method**, is to `mask` your conditions, which comes more closely to SQL aliases:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'POST_CREATED_AT': pd.date_range('20180128', periods=7),
                   'ID':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']})
print(df)
  POST_CREATED_AT ID
0      2018-01-28  A
1      2018-01-29  B
2      2018-01-30  C
3      2018-01-31  D
4      2018-02-01  E
5      2018-02-02  F
6      2018-02-03  G
```

---

```
m1 = df['POST_CREATED_AT'].between('20180201', '20180313', inclusive=False)
m2 = df['ID'] == 'G'

print(df[m1 & m2])

  POST_CREATED_AT ID
6      2018-02-03  G
```

Comment: Thx - maybe I should have specified _without resorting to string-based df.query_ (I am aware of that approach).  Your answer will in any case be helpful to others.

Comment: I see. Was already adding another method to my answer @javadba

Comment: I'm really looking for something like _aliases_ (not additional methods) - but in any case will upvote your answer as "likely helpful to readers"

Comment: @Efran FYI you can combine the strings in `query` like this: `df.query('20180201 < POST_CREATED_AT < 20180313')`